# VB.Net: Grade Calculator Program - Getting Ridiculous Values

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to create a grade calculator program and I am having some two problems:

1. Getting the right outputs (because I am getting ridiculous numbers) and
2. Getting my counters to work.

The basic form is basically one enters 7 input grades:

- 3 exams (weighed 15%, 20%, and 20% respectively)
- A project (weighed 10%),
- Assignments (weighed 20%),
- Peer reviews (weighed 5%) ,
- A programming language presentation (weighed 10%)

and the individual is supposed to get an output of their numeric grade, their letter grade, and two counters that count how many people got `A's` and `F's`.

For an example when I enter 3 exam grades: `82`,`87`,`91`; `Assignments: 94`; `Peer reviews: 100;` `programming language presentation: 90;` and `final project: 92,`

I get a final numeric grade of `253.90` and a letter grade of `F` when it clearly should be a letter grade of `A` and numeric `89.90`.

My counters also are not working properly because they aren't displaying the `count`, but I feel like I put it in the right place (displaying outputs). What exactly am I doing wrong here? Here's my code

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmGradeCalculator
    'declare Constants
    Const EXAM1GRADE_WEIGHT As Decimal = 0.15D
    Const EXAM2GRADE_WEIGHT As Decimal = 0.2D
    Const EXAM3GRADE_WEIGHT As Decimal = 0.2D
    Const HOMEWORKGRADE_WEIGHT As Decimal = 0.2D
    Const HOMEWORKPEERREVIEW_WEIGHT As Decimal = 0.05D
    Const LANGUAGEQUICKREFERENCE_WEIGHT As Decimal = 0.1D
    Const FINALPROJECT_WEIGHT As Decimal = 0.1D

    'Declare module variables
    Dim mdecFinalNumericGrade As Decimal
    Dim mstrFinalLetterGrade As String
    Dim mintStudentsWithAs As Integer
    Dim mintStudentsWithFs As Integer

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        'declare variables
        Dim decExam1Grade As Decimal
        Dim decExam2Grade As Decimal
        Dim decExam3Grade As Decimal
        Dim decHomeworkGrade As Decimal
        Dim decPeerReviewGrade As Decimal
        Dim decLanguageReferenceGrade As Decimal
        Dim decFinalProjectGrade As Decimal
        Dim decPercent As Decimal

        'check for blanks
        If (txtExam1Grade.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("You Can't Leave Exam 1 Blank")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for numeric
        If IsNumeric(txtExam1Grade.Text) = False Then 'value is not numeric
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Exam 1!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for blanks
        If (txtExam2Grade.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Exam 2!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'check for everything else
        If IsNumeric(txtExam2Grade.Text) = False Then 'Value is not numeric
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Exam 2!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for blanks
        If (txtExam3Grade.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Exam 3!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for numerics
        If IsNumeric(txtExam3Grade.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive numeric value for Exam3!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for blanks
        If (txtHomeworkGrade.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Homework Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for numerics
        If IsNumeric(txtHomeworkGrade.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric positive value for Homework Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for blanks
        If (txtPeerReviewGrade.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Peer Review Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for numerics
        If IsNumeric(txtPeerReviewGrade.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric positive value for Peer Review Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for blanks
        If (txtLanguageReferenceGrade.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Language Reference Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for numerics
        If IsNumeric(txtLanguageReferenceGrade.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric positive value for Language Reference Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'check for blanks
        If (txtFinalProjectGrade.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Final Project Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for numerics
        If IsNumeric(txtFinalProjectGrade.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric positive value for Final Project Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'convert data types
        decExam1Grade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtExam1Grade.Text)
        decExam2Grade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtExam2Grade.Text)
        decExam3Grade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtExam3Grade.Text)
        decHomeworkGrade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHomeworkGrade.Text)
        decPeerReviewGrade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPeerReviewGrade.Text)
        decLanguageReferenceGrade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtLanguageReferenceGrade.Text)
        decFinalProjectGrade = Convert.ToDecimal(txtFinalProjectGrade.Text)
        mdecFinalNumericGrade = (decExam1Grade * EXAM1GRADE_WEIGHT) + _
                                (decExam2Grade * EXAM2GRADE_WEIGHT) + _
                                (decExam3Grade * EXAM3GRADE_WEIGHT) + _
                                (decHomeworkGrade * HOMEWORKGRADE_WEIGHT) + _
                                (decPeerReviewGrade * HOMEWORKPEERREVIEW_WEIGHT) + _
                                (decLanguageReferenceGrade + LANGUAGEQUICKREFERENCE_WEIGHT) + _
                                (decFinalProjectGrade + FINALPROJECT_WEIGHT)

        'check for 0 or positive
        If decExam1Grade < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Exam 1!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for 0 or positive
        If decExam2Grade < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Exam 2!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for 0 or positive
        If decExam3Grade < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Exam 3!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for 0 or positive
        If decHomeworkGrade < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Homework Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for 0 or positive
        If decPeerReviewGrade < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Peer Review Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for 0 or positive
        If decLanguageReferenceGrade < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Language Reference!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'check for 0 or positive
        If decFinalProjectGrade < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive value or zero for Final Project Grade!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'make sure values are less than 100
        If decExam1Grade > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value thats 100 or less!")
        End If

        If decExam2Grade > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value thats 100 or less!")
        End If

        If decExam3Grade > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value thats 100 or less!")
        End If

        If decHomeworkGrade > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value thats 100 or less!")
        End If

        If decPeerReviewGrade > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value thats 100 or less!")
        End If

        If decLanguageReferenceGrade > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value thats 100 or less!")
        End If

        If decFinalProjectGrade > 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value thats 100 or less!")
        End If

        'Determine grade per letter
        Select Case decpercent
            Case Is >= 89.5D
                mstrFinalLetterGrade = "A"
                mintStudentsWithAs += 1
            Case Is >= 79.5D
                mstrFinalLetterGrade = "B"
            Case Is >= 69.5D
                mstrFinalLetterGrade = "C"
            Case Is >= 59.5D
                mstrFinalLetterGrade = "D"
            Case Else
                mstrFinalLetterGrade = "F"
                mintStudentsWithFs += 1
        End Select

        lblFinalLetterGrade.Text = mstrFinalLetterGrade

        'display outputs
        lblFinalNumericGrade.Text = mdecFinalNumericGrade.ToString("f2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        'clear the texboxes and labels
        txtExam1Grade.Clear()
        txtExam2Grade.Clear()
        txtExam3Grade.Clear()
        txtHomeworkGrade.Clear()
        txtPeerReviewGrade.Clear()
        txtLanguageReferenceGrade.Clear()
        txtFinalProjectGrade.Clear()
        lblFinalLetterGrade.Text = ""
        lblFinalNumericGrade.Text = ""

        'setcursor back to top textbox
        txtExam1Grade.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sende As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click

        'reset module level variables
        mdecFinalNumericGrade = 0
        mstrFinalLetterGrade = ""
        mintStudentsWithAs = 0
        mintStudentsWithFs = 0

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        'close the form
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmGradeCalculator_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I don't see where `decpercent` is declared or assigned a value, so your Select will always fall through to "F" because of the Else Case.

Comment: hey greg I am just getting a wrong numeric value and a letter grade value.  I mentioned in paragraphs three and four:                      For an example when I enter 3 exam grades: 82,87,91; Assignemnts: 94; Peer reviews: 100; programming language presentation: 90; and final project: 92,

I get a final numeric grade of 253.90 and a letter grade of F when it clearly should be a letter grade of A and numeric 89.90.

Answer (score 1):

Your final grade total is wrong because you're not multiplying the language presentation and final project by their weights, but adding the weight to the score:

- Exam1 = 82 * .15 = 12.3
- Exam2 = 87 * .20 = 17.4
- Exam3 = 91 * .20 = 18.2
- Assignments = 94 * .20 = 18.8
- Peer Review = 100 * .05 = 5
- Language Presentation = 90 + .10 = 90.1
- Final Project = 92 + .10 = 92.1

Notice the addition (rather than multiplication) on the last two values.  The total is 253.9.

Change the last two calculations for medcFinalNumericGrade to:

```
(decLanguageReferenceGrade * LANGUAGEQUICKREFERENCE_WEIGHT) + _
(decFinalProjectGrade * FINALPROJECT_WEIGHT)
```

You will always get an "F" because `decpercent` is never assigned a value, and therefore the Else Case is executed. Either assign decpercent a value, or use mdecFinalNumericGrade.

For example:

```
Select Case mdecFinalNumericGrade
```

instead of

```
Select Case decpercent
```

Once you fix the Select Case, your counts should work (unless you reset the form).